# Which type of statistical test should I use for categorical and continuous IVs and continuous DV?

Tags: regression, anova, t-test, repeated-measures, descriptive-statistics

I am conducting an experimental research. Research model shown as figure.

[image]

I hypothesized that X positively predicts Y. All participants were required to answer measurements of X and Y.

Meanwhile, three additional independent variables (conditions / wording of appeals: emotion, difficulty, effort) were manipulated and served as moderators of the X-Y direct relationship. There are eight conditions in total, and participants were randomly assigned to one of the eight conditions:

1. guilt / easy / low effort
2. guilt / easy / high effort
3. guilt / difficult / low effort
4. guilt / difficult / high effort
5. shame / easy / low effort
6. shame / easy / high effort
7. shame / difficult / low effort
8. shame / difficult / high effort

Put alternatively, my independent variable is a continuous variable and moderators are categorical variables whereas dependent variable is a continuous variable.

My question is: Which type of statistical test should I use?

Comment: Are you interested in Anova test or regression ?

Comment: I am interested in both ANOVA and regression. By the way, I use SPSS for data analysis.

Comment: scaling your categorical variable like guilt and shame as 0, 1 is obscure. you may have say, Likert scale etc. for one of two terms. I am not aware of  sample data. binary scale should be avoided.

Comment: @SubhashC.Davar Participants are randomly assigned to one of the conditions (i.e., guilt or shame + easy or difficult + low or high). So there are 8 manipulated conditions in total. Binary labelling is just for my easy reference.

Comment: You indicate 6 sets in your Chart. How is 8 number reached ?

Comment: And do these classifications reflect moderator variables ? What is the purpose of randomly assigned ?

Comment: @SubhashC.Davar I have further elaborated the research content which should be clearer now. Yes, those categorical variables (or conditions) serve as moderators of X-Y direct relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I think using a regression model would be good and then to test if the coefficient estimate of $X$ is 0 or not. The tests can be wald test, likelihood ratio test, score test, etc. You can choose one suitable and easy to use for your model.

Comment: Should I use a regression model even that the moderators (i.e., emotion, difficult, effort in this case) are categorical variables?

Comment: @James you can use a regression model provided you convert the categorical variable to its corresponding dummy variables. If your categorical variable has 3 levels you'll have n-1=2 dummy variables. In your data matrix you'll replace the original categorical column with the dummy variables.

Comment: What's the differences between using a regression model and ANCOVA?

Comment: Regression and ANOVA are two ways if you just want to do some test. Sometimes you need a model to do ANOVA, such as the null model and the specified model. Regression can give you more freedom to describe the relationship between the response variable and the independent variables. Perhaps you can choose one of them based on what results you want.

Comment: Another way to include categorical variables in the model is to convert them into factors, which will be automatically converted into dummy variables by the model function.